# Luabind setting property of derived type with base type

Tags: c++, binding, casting, lua, luabind

I am using LuaBind to expose c++ classes to Lua scripts. I have ran into a problem with the inability to cast a base class to its derived class. I have a factory class that returns objects of a base type. There are some fields of a type derived from the base type that I am trying to set with these objects. I have boiled down my problem into some test code that can reproduce the issue and explain it clearer.

#### c++ Class Definitions

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void say() { cout << "a" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  virtual void say() { cout << "b" << endl; }
};

class TestClass {
public:
  Base *GetBase() { return (Base *)new Derived(); }
  Derived *derivedRef;
};
```

#### c++ LuaBind Binding Code

```
module(L)[
    class_<Base>("Base")
    .def(constructor<>())
    .def("say", &Base::say)];

module(L)[class_<Derived, Base>("Derived")
    .def(constructor<>())
    .def("say", &Derived::say)];

module(L)[class_<TestClass>("TestClass")
    .def(constructor<>())
    .def("GetBase", &TestClass::GetBase)
    .def_readwrite("derivedRef", &TestClass::derivedRef)];
```

#### Lua Code

```
testClass = TestClass()
base = testClass:GetBase()
testClass.derivedRef = base
```

#### Error

```
 occurred executing a LUA script: No matching overload found, candidates: 
 void <unknown>(TestClass&,Derived* const&)
```

Does anyone know if upcasting is even possible in LuaBind and if so how I should go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long process I solved this problem.

First I read [here](http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Luabind-0-9-td7583076.html) that the version of LuaBind I am running (0.9) should support automatic down/up casting of types when passed into parameters. This showed that it was possible.

I then found out [here](http://oberon00.github.io/luabind/classes.html#additional-support-for-shared-ptr-and-intrusive-ptr) that there is a special header to include for converting shared pointers (which I realised I was using). The converter that comes with LuaBind only works with boost shared pointers. It was pretty simple to get the [source for the boost smart pointer converter](https://github.com/LuaDist/luabind/blob/master/luabind/shared_ptr_converter.hpp) and replace every instance of boost:: with std:: and make [a few small modifications](https://gist.github.com/NoxHarmonium/8fb5196a0d3e8eb534d2) so it would compile.

I then started getting errors that said

```
std::runtime_error: 'Trying to use unregistered class'
```

when I was calling bind methods.

There was a version of a shared pointer converter [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/luabind/mailman/message/31145088/) but it didn't compile on my machine. I used it as a reference to make another [header file](https://gist.github.com/NoxHarmonium/c4224d3a6d4cab855e8c) which allows LuaBind to bind shared pointers from the standard library.

To make a long story short, include the following two files and automatic up/down casting of shared pointers work when you use the standard library version rather than the boost version.

- [std_shared_ptr_converter.hpp](https://gist.github.com/NoxHarmonium/8fb5196a0d3e8eb534d2)
- [FixStdSharedPtrBind.h](https://gist.github.com/NoxHarmonium/c4224d3a6d4cab855e8c)

I am using Xcode 5 with a clang compiler and I haven't tested it with another compiler.